# Can iPhone used for Bluetooth file exchange programatically. (Without using WiFi/NFC)

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I am looking into how to exchange files between multiple iOS devices using Bluetooth 4.0.
I googled for the same but not able to find any appropriate answer.
Also I am not sure if it is feasible or not.

What frameworks are better to use to do that? Will Core Bluetooth do the work, or GameKit?

Any help, tips, recommendations will be appreciated.

Comment: You can use `L2CAP` in Core Bluetooth.  You could also use MultiPeer Connectivity; the nice thing about that is it will use WiFi if it is available

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11 for the reply. I am just asking about file exchange only via Bluetooth with keeping Wifi Off. (Don't want to use Wifi / Airdrop / NFC etc.) for iOS 9 and above devices

Comment: Sure, you could use Multipeer connectivity for Bluetooth, but I don't think it uses L2CAP, so it will probably be slow for file transfers.  You might want to create your own solution using CoreBluetooth directly. I was merely pointing out that MultiPeer abstracts the connectivity and will use whatever is available, Bluetooth or WiFi, without you needing to worry about it in your code.